# Image throws 404 Error when using app on server

Tags: html, angular, image

Hi I checked several answers around the web but none of these worked yet, I located the image where it supposed to be by the most answers. The problem is that I have a loader component which contains a loader that pops up when doing something in my application and it needs some time to load. In local it works perfectly but when I use it on server it throws GET 404 error for the image that needs to be shown inside the loader circle. I'm using Angular 7.

Currently I have the image here: `src/assets/image/logo.jpg`

And this is how it looks in the component: `<img src="../../assets/image/logo.jpg">`

my workspace is like this: `src --> app --> loader --> loadingComponent`

What can cause the problem that it works good in local but doesn't work when I run the app on Tomcat server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what worked for me is using the source like this: `<img src="assets/image/logo.jpg">` I removed the `/` sign before `assets`. Now its working fine on server as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change your image src to absolute path.

```
<img src="/assets/image/logo.jpg">
```

You should consider situation, when you use your component somewhere deeper in your app. This would brake your relative path, so absolute path is better solution.

`/assets` directory is served from root path by default, so you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Your image src should be relative to the root of the app.

I assume your assets folder is in the root, as per the standard Angular build.

If so, your image element should look like this:

```
<img src="/assets/image/logo.jpg">
```

This has the effect of forming the full url

```
http://myapp.com/assets/image/logo.jpg
```

If that still fails, try to load the image in your browser using the full url, and reverse engineer it to your image src.

Comment: well it still fails, I will try to reverse it from the url

Comment: Also, have you checked that the image was in the build, and exists on the server?

Comment: I checked it now and it's there

Comment: Are you able to post the image url and page it's meant to be on? No problem if you'd rather not.

Comment: I tracked it back and looks like it throws error because it misses a ```/hm``` before the ```assets/image/logo.jpg```

Comment: So that's down to your folder structure? But the fact that your `src` should be relative to the root is also correct?

Comment: Its not in my folder structure, my folder is default as it is in angular. It comes from the server side, this ```/hm``` is before every pages URL, I didn't notice that it uses in the path of the image too

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant folder structure in general, not just your app.